# Json server POST request not working by axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, vue.js, nativescript

Hello Im using this json server https://github.com/typicode/json-server
I can post data in postmman and its working good for example object

```
{  
   "mainTab":{  
      "m_actual":0,
      "m_refresh":2000,
      "m_actual":0,
      "m_refresh":4000
     } 
  }
```

with header `Content-Type: application/json`
To my server is running http://35.195.249.40:3004/users

**And everything is ok**

But on my app in nativescript/vue I cant make post request - its gives 304 response

```
updateJsonData(){
            const data = {

                m_actualHP: 0,
                m_refreshHP: 2000,
                m_actualMP: 666666,
                m_refreshMP: 4000,

            }

        axios.post('http://35.195.249.40:3004/users', data, {
                headers:  { 
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'

                     }
                }
             )
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);

            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }); 

     },
```

I tried with fetch request too and it response 
'parsing failed: ' [TypeError: Network request failed: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to not permitted]

```
 updateJsonData(){ 
        fetch('http://35.195.249.40:3004/users', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "title":   "Add a blogpost about Angular2",
                "dueDate": "2015-05-23T18:25:43.511Z",
                "done": false
            })
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response.json()
                }).then(function(json) {
                console.log('parsed json: ', json)
                }).catch(function(ex) {
                console.log('parsing failed: ', ex)
                });

    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Postman example object you provided

```
{  
   "mainTab": {  
      "m_actual":0,
      "m_refresh":2000,
      "m_actual":0,
      "m_refresh":4000
     } 
  }
```

The fields are embedded in an object accessible via the `mainTab` key.
However, in your actual code examples you are providing the object with the desired fields (like `m_refresh`) directly and not in an embedded manner.

So, my suggestion is to wrap the object containing the data to make the posting call look like this:

```
axios.post('http://35.195.249.40:3004/users', { mainTab: data },
  {
    headers:  { 
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: in postman I provided in nested object "mainTab":{} becouse i try different things but its not the case here. In Postman it works whatever I post here but In my vue its not

Comment: Could you maybe attach a sample error response? That would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

these provided axios.post provide this code in response

```
    { data: '',
JS:   status: null,
JS:   statusText: '',
JS:   headers: {},
JS:   config:
JS:    { adapter: { [Function: xhrAdapter] [length]: 1, [name]: 'xhrAdapter', [prototype]: [Object] },
JS:      transformRequest: { '0': [Object] },
JS:      transformResponse: { '0': [Object] },
JS:      timeout: 0,
JS:      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
JS:      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
JS:      maxContentLength: -1,
JS:      validateStatus: { [Function: validateStatus] [length]: 1, [name]: 'validateStatus', [prototype]: [Object] },
JS:      headers:
JS:       { Accept: 'application/json',
JS:         'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
JS:      method: 'post',
JS:      url: 'http://35.195.249.40:3004/users',
JS:      data: '{"data":{"mainTab":{"m_actualHP":0,"m_refreshHP":2000,"m_actualMP":666666,"m_refreshMP":4000}}}' },
JS:   request:
JS:    { UNSENT: 0,
JS:      OPENED: 1,
JS:      HEADERS_RECEIVED: 2,
JS:      LOADING: 3,
JS:      DONE: 4,
JS:      _responseType: '',
JS:      textTypes:
JS:       [ 'text/plain',
JS:         'application/xml',
JS:         'application/rss+xml',
JS:         'text/html',
JS:         'text/xml',
JS: ...
JS: 'CONSOLE LOG END | CONSOLE DIR STARTS'
JS: ==== object dump start ====
JS: data: ""
JS: status: "null"
JS: statusText: ""
JS: headers: {}
JS: config: {
JS:   "transformRequest": {},
JS:   "transformResponse": {},
JS:   "timeout": 0,
JS:   "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
JS:   "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
JS:   "maxContentLength": -1,
JS:   "headers": {
JS:     "Accept": "application/json",
JS:     "Content-Type": "application/json"
JS:   },
JS:   "method": "post",
JS:   "url": "http://35.195.249.40:3004/users",
JS:   "data": "{\"data\":{\"mainTab\":{\"m_actualHP\":0,\"m_refreshHP\":2000,\"m_actualMP\":666666,\"m_refreshMP\":4000}}}"
JS: }
JS: request: {
JS:   "UNSENT": 0,
JS:   "OPENED": 1,
JS:   "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
JS:   "LOADING": 3,
JS:   "DONE": 4,
JS:   "_responseType": "",
JS:   "textTypes": [
JS:     "text/plain",
JS:     "application/xml",
JS:     "application/rss+xml",
JS:     "text/html",
JS:     "text/xml"
JS:   ],
JS:   "_listeners": {},
JS:   "_readyState": 4,
JS:   "_options": {
JS:     "url": "http://35.195.249.40:3004/users",
JS:     "method": "POST",
JS:     "headers": {
JS:       "Accept": "application/json",
JS:       "Content-Type": "application/json"
JS:     },
JS:     "content": "{\"data\":...
```

**I figured out axios would not work with http. It needs https.
Is there possibility to make it working without https?**

other solution could be running json server with https.
Im using this server so what im doing im make npm start in ubuntu and server starts
https://github.com/halfzebra/json-server-example

there is written on github to use https://github.com/typicode/hotel this to provide https but it working on localhost. I need to run it on global IP over https

Comment: Hi Karolek, not familiar with the matter, this does Not look like an answer to me. If so, please edit your question to add supplements and remove this, if it  should be an answer, just respond to my comment and I'll remove it.